# How to I position elements relative to a non-parent item?

Tags: html, css

I have the following set up on my page:

[image]

I want to position the input elements relative to the table below it and I want them justified to the right and I want this to happen no matter what size the table is (because different tables will be different sizes but have similar inputs).

How would I go about accomplishing this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
form {
    float: right;
    margin-right: /* until it looks good */
}
```

That will accomplish what you're looking for. If you want it to be truly relative to the table, you'll need to put it *inside* the table and given it a negative top margin. Or, put both in one parent div and make them both equally relative to the parent div.

Comment: Ok, so that idea actually had occured to me but in testing I couldn't really get it to work out quite right. Do I have to make it a table row and all that or can I just put the form inside the <table> tag?

Comment: Nevermind dude, you pointed me in the right direction and I figured it out.